# Restoring queues in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

In the cases where my program is training for a long time and stops for whatever reason I would like to be able to start off from near the latest checkpoint. I am using queues and I have no problem restoring most of the variables with

```
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            merged = s.summarize_variables()
            merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
            train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(save_dir + '/train',sess.graph)
            eval_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(save_dir + '/test')
            sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
            saver = tf.train.Saver()
            tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess, coord=coord)
            if model_file:
                saver.restore(sess, model_file)
            try:
                while not coord.should_stop():
                    tflearn.is_training(True)
                    cur_step = sess.run(global_step)
```

When I restore the model I find the queues are not finishing when they should. How do I restore the queus to their state when the checkpoint was created?